# Consolidating two text files with Python

Tags: python, iteration, text-processing, text-parsing

Im trying to iterate through two different text files and create one consolidated file based on the account number found at the beginning of each line in both files. I begin by reading the main file which contains statement data and  read each line until I find an account number that doesn't match the previous line, I then start iterating through the second file and try to match up any matching account numbers with the previous block from file 1. I am having trouble when I get to this part.

Some sample data would be:

File1 ....     File2
000990     000990 is my partner
000990     000990 is my partner
000760     000530 is my partner
000760     000530 is my partner
000530     000999 is my partner
000530     000999 is my partner
000999

Desired Output
000990
000990
000990 is my partner
000990 is my partner
000760
000760
000530
000530
000530 is my partner
000530 is my partner
000999
000999 is my partner
000999 is my partner

This is the code I have tried so far. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```
x=open('testaccount.txt')
y=open('accountpartner.txt')
count=1
inv_count=1
for line in x:
    if count==1:
        a=x.readline()
        print('S'+line, end='')
    if line[0:6]==a[0:6]:
        print('S'+line, end='')
    elif line[0:6]!=a[0:6]:
        for inv_line in y:
            if inv_count==1:
                b=y.readline()
                if b[0:6]==a[0:6]:
                    print('I',b,end='')
        inv_count+=1
        print('break')
        print('S'+line,end='')
        a=line
        count=1
        continue
    count+=1
print('this is a',a)
```

Comment: "I am having trouble when I get to this part."?  What trouble?  Which Part?  Please clarify your question to be very **specific** on the exact trouble and the exact part.

Comment: I am able to iterate through the first file and seperate it into chunks, but I can't seem to figure out how to match up the corresponding chunks from file 2 so that they print one right after the other(as in the sample outout above) and write them all out to one file. If you run the code with the sample data i provided you will see the results I am getting. Sorry, I am still a novice and this code is in it's early stages.

Comment: Please **update** the question to clarify your specific problem.  Please do not add more comments to your question.  It's **your** question.  Please **update** it to be complete and clear.  We really don't have the time to download and run this for ourselves.  We need you to pinpoint **your** problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use dictionaries for this.  It's much simpler that writing your own sort-merge.

```
with open('accountpartner.txt') as aFile:
    lookup = {}
    for line in aFile:
        lookup[line[:6]]= line

def make_groups( source ):
    group = []
    key= None
    for line in source:
        if line[:6] != key:
            if group: yield key, group
            group= []
            key= line[:6]
        group.append( line )
    if group: yield key, group

with open('testaccount.txt') as main:
    for key, group in make_groups( main ):
        if key in lookup:
            print key, group, lookup
        else:
            print key, group, None
```